# Why there's a need to declare an abstract. I need alternative way to implement DirectionFinderListener on my Main Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Error on Direction Finder:

> Class DirectionFinder must either be declared abstract or implement
>   abstract method onDirectionFinderStart in DirectionFinderListener

[HERE] Direction Finder.. Is there anyway to implement DirectionFinderListener here??

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivityLocation
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, DirectionFinderListener {
```

or

```
public class DirectionFinder implements DirectionFinderListener {

}
```

Also, if I put abstract here. I am getting  Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends BaseActivityLocation
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, DirectionFinderListener {
```

Interface:
Here's where I am getting an error. 
I cannot implement onDirectionFinderStart() on my MainActivity.

```
public interface DirectionFinderListener {
    void onDirectionFinderStart();
    void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> route);
}
```

Comment: ***I cannot implement onDirectionFinderStart() on my MainActivity.*** why not??

Comment: Hi ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ, it gives me this error Class MainActivity must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onDirectionFinderStart in DirectionFinderListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question comes down to a handful of Java basics. What is an `abstract` class? What does it mean to `implement` an interface. Etc. I can attempt to give you a quick overview, but you should do some more reading on your own.

An interface is a set of methods. Classes can declare that they `implement` the interface, but by doing so they are making a commitment that they will support the methods defined in the interface.

An `abstract` class is one that can't be instantiated. What's the point? An abstract class can define `abstract` methods. Like an interface, the class is guaranteeing that *someone* is going to write a subclass and *that class* will support those methods.

Taken together you have your answer. If you add `implements DirectionFinderListener` to your class declaration, you have two options: either implement all methods listed in `DirectionFinderListener`, or declare your class `abstract`. If you declare your class `abstract`, you will not be able to instantiate it (you will have to write some subclass that implements all the methods you chose not to implement in your superclass, and you will be able to instantiate that).

Abstract classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Interfaces: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html